# How do I downgrade from Swift 4 to Swift 3?

Tags: swift, swift3, swift4

I just upgraded my code from Swift 3 to Swift 4. Later, I changed my mind and wanted to use my code with iOS 10. Then I got this error:

> “Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured
>   correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit > Convert > To
>   Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or use the Build
>   Settings editor to configure the build setting directly.

I used the [Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version but then it said

> 'No Filter Results'.

Then, I tried to use Build Settings and changed 'SWIFT_VERSION' from 4.0 to 3.1 and also 3.0. However, the error persisted. Does anyone know a solution to this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hopefully you keep your project committed to source control such as git. Reverting in git seems like the best option you have.

Comment: Create new project and add your source files there.

Comment: .. at least, there is no reason why the swift 4 can not be used on iOS10

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Clean your project (CMD + Shift + K) and make sure the `SWIFT_VERSION` on every target is set to Swift 3 using Xcode 8.3.3

Comment: got a prompt which states:
The document "Main.storyboard" requires Xcode 9.0 or later
Is there another adjustment to make for IB?

Comment: You'll have to open the storyboard as source code and delete the xcode 9 line.

Comment: life saver! Thank you